# What is the most typographically safe way to write a linear program in R?

Tags: r, linear-programming

In R, linear programming using the [lpsolve](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/) library requires an extensive amount of manually typed values for the needed matrices and vectors for the objective function coefficients, left-hand side coefficients, constraints, etc. Messing up even one value or one comma will make the script error or worse, the program will find a solution but it will be the wrong one due to incorrect setup. For large, real-world problems like network flow, simply typing the program itself is time prohibitive. What am I missing about R's capabilities in this space? Or, is there an alternate tool better fit for the job? Open source preferred due to budget.

Here is an example of the type of code needed in R for a relatively simple optimization problem:

```
# fleet size optimization, with an added computation of total miles driven
library(lpSolve)

# Objective function coefficients
ObjCoeff<-c(1300, 690, 421.5, 531, 690, 427.50, 277.50, 421.5, 427.50, 303, 531, 277.50, 303,
            460, 281,   354, 460, 285,    185,    281,   285,    202, 354, 185,    202, 0)

# Constraint matrix            
Amatrix<-matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                  
                  0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1,  0, 0, -1, 0, 0,0,
                  0, -1,0, 0,  1, 1, 1,  0, -1, 0, 0,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0,  1, 1, 1,  0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0,0,
                  0, 0,-1, 0,  0,-1, 0,  1,  1, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0,-1, 0, 0, -1, 0,  1,  1, 1, 0,  0,-1,0,
                  0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0,-1,  0,  0,-1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,-1, 0,  0,-1,  0,  0,-1, 1,  1, 1,0,
                  -1300, 460, 281,354,460,285,185,281,285,202,354,185,202,460,281,354, 460, 285,185, 281, 285,202, 354, 185, 202, 0,
                  0, 460, 281,354,460,285,185,281,285,202,354,185,202,460,281,354, 460, 285,185, 281, 285,202, 354, 185, 202,-1), nrow=18, byrow=TRUE)

# Right hand side constraint vector                  
Bvector<-c(10, 10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0 )

# Constraint inequality direction vector
constrainttype<- c(">=", ">=",">=", ">=",">=", ">=",">=", ">=",">=", ">=",">=", ">=","=", "=" , "=" , "=" ,"<=", "=" )

# Solve the specified integer program by setting all.int=TRUE
optimum<-lp(direction="min", objective.in=ObjCoeff, const.mat = Amatrix, const.dir = constrainttype, const.rhs = Bvector, all.int =TRUE)

# Print constraint matrix to verify it was specified correctly
print(optimum$constraints)

# Check to see if the solver reached optimality (0 means yes)
print(optimum$status)

# Print values of each variable in the optimal solution
# note that they are all integer valued
print(optimum$solution)

# Print the optimal objective function value
print(optimum$objval)
```

Comment: It will be easier for people to help if you could provide a concrete example of code that people could run, and for which they could try to suggest an improvement.

Comment: @JonSpring good point, I updated the question with an example.

Comment: From your example, I would suggest storing the `Amatrix` matrix as a flat file, not in code. As a CSV or TSV file you can edit it in any number of programs that are made for viewing and editing CSV files -- obviously Excel works, but there's plenty of other light-weight editors that won't aggressively convert fields to dates ;)

Comment: The [**ompr**](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/kantorovichWithOMPR.html) package has a user-friendly syntax.

Comment: lpSolve package has a different interface to lpSolve and can read MPS files.  linprog can too.  Also see https://upcommons.upc.edu/bitstream/handle/2117/78335/Modeling+and+Solving+Linear+Programming+with+R.pdf?sequence=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R has its strengths for sure, but formulation of non-trivial LP's is *not* one of them.

There are several other open source frameworks that are much more expressive.  If you are a `python` user, you can pick from many including:

`pyomo, gekko, cvxpy, pulp, or-tools` and others I'm sure.

I'm a fan of `pyomo` for model building, but it requires installation of a separate solver, which isn't too difficult.  There are several open-source free solvers that are excellent and in common use with different capabilities such as `cbc, glpk, ipopt` and others, and of course many excellent licensed solvers.

If you want to start with an "all in one" the `pulp` framework includes a solver with the build--I forget which one.

There are many examples on this site for all the pkgs above if you search by tag.

Comment: Thank you, this Answer and the comments above all contribute meaningfully to either a) executing linear programming in R via simpler, human-friendly means or b) alternate tools other than R that do so to an even greater degree. Thanks to everyone for their contributions. :)